# Stop a preview from being generated?

Tags: dropzone.js

I wanted uploads to occur only if a certain other condition (metadata for the file being uploaded has been supplied elsewhere on the page) is true.  Otherwise, don't start the upload and don't even create a preview.  Just put up an `alert` saying the metadata needs to be entered before any items can be uploaded.

I can indeed preempt the upload in the `accept` handler by calling the supplied `done` function with a non-null argument. E.g.

```
done("You need to enter a UPC code for this image.");
return false;
```

However, the preview is still created, with the `error` overlay.

I tried several approaches, including catching the `drop` event with no success.  It still wants to put up a preview even when I cancel the event including any further, downstream processing.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Not so much a question as looking to save others some pain.  The wiki is somewhat difficult to find and even harder to add anything to, and I see other, similar q's being asked on s/o.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is make a question and at the same time provide an answer, then you should do it, but you should try to do it correctly, you should rephrase the question to be actually a question and then answer the question yourself. see https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the answer was perhaps too simple: I needed to call `removeFile` in the `accept` handler.

So, my `accept` handler looks something like this:

```
accept: function(file) {
  if (/* condition not met */) {
    alert("You haven't met the condition. No upload for you!");
    deleteOnServer = false;
    this.removeFile(file);
    deleteOnServer = true;
    return false;
  }

  /* otherwise, do normal "accept" processing. */
```

Note that since I also have a flag I check for when all I want to do is remove files from the dropzone, but leave them alone on the server.  (I.e., I may be uploading to replace one that's already there.)  So, I 
register a "removedFile" event handler in my Dropzone `init` function:

```
init:  function() {
  this.on("removedFile", function(file) {
    if (!deleteOnServer) {
        return false;
    }

    /* otherwise, send $.ajax(DELETE) request to server */
       :
  }
```